# Unintelligible Batch of Wingdinglish

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

*How do you even read these runes?*

[image: Wingdinglish]

*Note: Click image for full size*

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE!

Comment: Why would you call these runes?

Comment: You can also easily decipher these by using the frequency analysis tactic.

Comment: Aaah! Very creative! +1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As described in [Gareth's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61853/20521) (go upvote that if you haven't already), the first step is to notice that:

> the white background isn't all quite white, and a bit of colour remapping produces [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoRmt.png).

From there, a bit of cryptogram work led us to what was written in the texts, as well as the scripts they were written in:

> Alphabet: Aquarion Alphabet
>  SAYAKA MIKI: Puella Magi Madoka Magica character
>  SONY STORAGE FORMAT USING ATRAC: MiniDisc
>
>  Alphabet: Human Alphabet in "Is It Wrong to Try to Pick Up Girls in a Dungeon?"
>  SHADOW ANGEL: main antagonists of Genesis of Aquarion
>  LEAD WEAPON IN CLUE: pipe
>
>  Alphabet: Konosuba Alphabet
>  DOKUROXY: Villain in Mahou Tsukai Pretty Cure!
>  LAST BUT BLANK LEAST: not
>
>  Alphabet: Luna Alphabet (Little Witch Academia)
>  ELSIE: The World God Only Knows character
>  SPEEDY PARR KID: Dash
>
>  Alphabet: Precure Alphabet
>  CH POSTAL COMPANY: Company in Violet Evergarden
>  TYPE OF CORRECTION OR RAY: gamma
>
>  Alphabet: Imanity Alphabet (No Game No Life)
>  DR. GEL: antagonist in Space Dandy
>  GARACHINE AIRPORT CODE: GHE
>
>  Alphabet: Unovian Alphabet (Pokémon)
>  ORARIO: City in Is It Wrong to Try to Pick Up Girls in a Dungeon?
>  MUSICAL BUILDUP OF LOUDNESS: crescendo
>
>  Alphabet: Witch runes (Puella Magi Madoka Magica)
>  EXPLOOOSION: Megumin's [signature spell chant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coYieIF8I5M) in Konosuba
>  TRACK EIGHT FROM STARRS ALBUM RINGO: "Six O'Clock"
>
>  Alphabet: Space Dandy Alphabet
>  ENCHANTED PARADE: Little Witch Academia series subtitle
>  WORD AFTER ZERO FLUTE RHYMING WITH DRINK: countersink
>
>  Alphabet: Zentradi Alphabet (Super Dimension Fortress Macross)
>  BEST WISHES: Pokémon series subtitle
>  WORD AFTER EUROPEAN OR TRADE: union
>
>  Alphabet: Leiden Alphabet (Violet Evergarden)
>  OLD DEUS: race in No Game No Life
>  THINK WORK SERVE SCHOOL INITS: TSU
>
>  Alphabet: Hell Alphabet (The World God Only Knows)
>  MY BOYFRIEND IS A PILOT (Super Dimension Fortress Macross song)
>  EARLY BYZANTINE GOLD COIN: solidus

We can notice that for each block of text,

> The first line refers to one of the anime the scripts come from, and the second line gives a word that represents a symbol. For instance, solidus is another name for slash, and the mathematical symbol for union is ∪.

Then @Deusovi brilliantly noticed that

> The symbols described are all part of the [Moon type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_type) writing system, giving the letters, in order: HIMTEEKIVUDS

The final step is to

> Reorder the blocks in a cycle, in which the anime reference for one block is where the alphabet for the next block in the cycle comes from. The starting point of the cycle is the Luna Alphabet block, as indicated by the arrow pointing to it in the image. Doing so gives us the letters TSUKIHIME DEV:
>
>  [image]

Giving us the final answer...

> Type-Moon. Quite fitting.

As a side note,

> The initials to this puzzle's title, Unintelligible Batch of Wingdinglish, are the same as those of Unlimited Blade Works, another TYPE-MOON creation.

Comment: I'm disappointed in myself now for not recognising the witch runes. I'm also not surprised that this puzzle was solved by a user with a Konosuba avatar.

Answer (score 27):

It says

> THINGS LOOK A BIT OFF DONT THEY

if we

> replace each wingding character with the character at the same code point in the ordinary ASCII character set.

This isn't all; it turns out that

> the white background isn't all quite white, and a bit of colour-remapping produces this:
>  [image: ![enter image description here]

I confess that

> transcribing all of this and either treating it as cryptograms or identifying whatever (presumably artificial) scripts they use seems ... more like work than fun. If I find the energy to decipher any of it, I will report here :-).

Many of these

> seem to be letter-for-letter transcriptions of (more or less) English text, with the symbols used here often somewhat resembling the corresponding ones in our familiar Latin alphabet.

Block 1:

> Pretty sure this says SAYAKA MIKI / SONY STORAGE FORMAT USING ATRAC. First part is an anime character, who is apparently known to fans of the anime as "Blue"; second perhaps "MiniDisc".

Block 2:

> Looks like SHADOW ANGEL / LEAD WEAPON IN CLU. First might be "demon" or something; second perhaps "pipe" if we assume there's an omitted "e". (Thanks to F1Krazy for getting started on this one.)

Block 3: (not really looked at yet)

Block 4: (not really looked at yet, but)

> I suspect the individual "characters" here may be vertical groups of three symbols rather than single symbols.

Block 5:

> Looks like CM POSTAL COMPANY / TYPE OF CORRECTION OR RAY. Second bit is probably GAMMA (thanks @ffao; I had had a strictly inferior idea for that).

Block 6: (not really looked at yet)

Block 7: (not really looked at yet)

Block 8: (not really looked at yet, but)

> one word appears to have three successive "S" characters (if that's what they are) which is ... unusual. Also, one word looks a lot like ALSO.

Block 9:

> qiupqiup seems to think this should say ENCHANTED PARADE / WORD AFTER ZERO FLUTE RHYMING / WITH DRINK; if so, presumably it's three things divided differently: enchanted parade, word after zero (tolerance? one? gravity? ...), flute rhyming with drink.

Block 10: (not really looked at yet)

Block 11: (not really looked at yet)

Block 12: (not really looked at yet)

Comment: I suspect there's something more to this puzzle...

Comment: Damn, just beat me to that edit...

Comment: @LatchyArcherLeadr did you create this conscript? Its really nice.

Comment: It's clearly not *one* script but many.

Comment: Sorry conscript*s* (plural). They look vaguely familiar (I study conscripts them in my freetime)

Comment: I would go with "gamma" for correction or ray, personally...

Comment: Also, "wits drink" should actually be "with", both because it makes more sense and because the symbol matches the other Hs. "word after zero flute rhyming with drink" can be countersink.

Comment: Ah, probably a mistranscription on my part. Good spot; thanks!

Comment: First line of the second block is "--a-o- angel".

Comment: Could well be. If so, almost certainly "shadow".

Comment: @ffao Yes, "gamma" is a much better bet than "laser". Nice one.

Comment: Yeah, "shadow angel", and then "lead weapon in Clue" (which is "pipe").

Comment: Indeed. (I got there independently, as it happens :-).)

Comment: if CM is the country code for cameroon, their postal company appears to be called CAMPOST

Answer (score 8):

If we use

> a Least Significant Bit detector,

we can find:

> [image]

However these runes currently elude me...

The fifth block appears to say:

> ... CM Postal Company, Type of correction or ray

Answer (score 4):

## Wrap-up:  The Making Of *Unintelligible Batch of Wingdinglish*

*This is not a solution to the puzzle, but provides notes from its poser. This type of answer has been [approved by the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/).*

---

Just a number of comments not covered by the other answers, and also some background.

> - This puzzle's presentation is intended to be a mega version of [this puzzle by @Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61750/when-was-this-marvelous-thing-first-invented), posted two days earlier.
>
>  - Wingdinglish is a reference to [this TVTropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Wingdinglish), which as of writing mentions two of the alphabets used.
>
>  - [@Fifth_H0r5eman's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61854/46455) makes this slightly more obvious than [@Gareth McCaughan's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61853/46455), but in addition to the white pixels, some of the black pixels are one bit off.
>
>  - Some of these alphabets have been turned into useable fonts by fans. Whilst using such fonts would improve readability, it would look odd if half the puzzle was tablet-drawn, even if the alternative meant wrangling with [Imanity-go](http://no-game-no-life.wikia.com/wiki/Imanity-go).
>
>  - Some candidate alphabets had to be cut due to mapping to Japanese kana instead of English letters, or due to difficulty of research.
>
>  - Alphabet selection was influenced by how much I verified and trusted the charts used. [Primary sources](http://www.toei-anim.co.jp/tv/mahotsukai_precure/special/) were preferable but usually not available, alas.
>
>  - @Deusovi managed to skip this step, but reading the first lines in chain order (ELSIE, MY BOYFRIEND IS A PILOT, ...) spells out EMBOSSED CODE.
>
>  - Due to the first letters restriction, assigning good first-line clues proved surprisingly tricky, especially due to not being familiar with some of the series involved. As such some clues ended up referencing a franchise rather than the specific entry within the franchise, e.g. SHADOW ANGEL is more a reference to [Genesis of Aquarion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_of_Aquarion), rather than its sequel [Aquarion EVOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquarion_Evol) which provides the alphabet used.
>
>  - At least one clue was scrapped to avoid solvers potentially researching their way into spoilers, even though it would have improved the puzzle.
>
>  - At least one clue was tweaked due to different circulated fan charts conflicting on the character used.
>
>  - As @ffao points out, the title initals UBW is a reference to Unlimited Blade Works, part of the [Fate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate/stay_night) universe by Type-Moon.